# Rails 5 set Authorization header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5

I got JSON Web Token login going but am in the process of fixing my Rails 5 Controller tests.

I am trying to pass my JWT auth token to my GET request header.

So far, in my User Controller test, I have this test:

```
test "users should return list of users" do
    User.create(@bob)
    auth_token = log_in_as(@bob)

    request.headers['Authorization'] = "JWT #{auth_token}"    
    get users_path    
    assert_response :success

    assert_not response.body.empty?
  end
```

So far that doesn't work, I get response `not authenticated`.

If I change it to like so:

```
 test "users should return list of users" do
    User.create(@bob)
    auth_token = log_in_as(@bob)

    get users_path, nil, { HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: "JWT #{auth_token}" }

    puts "response = #{response.body}"

    assert_response :success

    assert_not response.body.empty?
  end
```

I get this expected response:

```
response = {"users":[{"id":298486374,"name":"MyString","email":"MyString","cats":[]},{"id":980190962,"name":"MyString","email":"MyString","cats":[]},{"id":980190963,"name":"Bob","email":"bob@gmail.com","cats":[]}]}
```

but I also get a DEPRECATED WARNING:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest HTTP request
>   methods will accept only the following keyword arguments in future
>   Rails versions: params, headers, env, xhr
>
> Examples:
>
> get '/profile',   params: { id: 1 },   headers: { 'X-Extra-Header' =>
>   '123' },   env: { 'action_dispatch.custom' => 'custom' },   xhr: true

So what is the recommended way to set HTTP Authorization header in Rails 5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the params and headers key in the arguments [see here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1515).

```
get users_path, params: {}, headers: { HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: "JWT #{auth_token}" }
```

You first example probably isn't working because you are setting the JWT on Authorization and not HTTP_AUTHORIZATION.

```
 request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = "JWT #{auth_token}"
```

Comment: Using `request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = "JWT #{auth_token}"` didn't work either. The `headers: { ... }` method works though.

Comment: Using the `:headers` keyword argument works in my request specs but in my controller specs I have to modify `request.headers` for it to work.